# installing harfbuzz 1.0.1 on CentOS 5

Tags: centos, harfbuzz

I'm trying to install harfbuzz-1.0.1 on a CentOS 5 machine where I do NOT have sudo access, and hence need to install into non-standard locations. I have downloaded and unpacked the source code, and added what I believe to be the relevant dependences to my `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH`. These packages include:

- freetype2
- icu-uc

Checking that '$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` is correct:

```
$pkg-config --modversion freetype2
9.22.3
$pkg-config --modversion icu-uc
55.1
```

Within the unpacked source directory, I ran:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/some/custom/path
# produces lots of output, but summary here
Build configuration:

Unicode callbacks (you want at least one):
    Glib:           true
    ICU:            true
    UCDN:           false

Font callbacks (the more the better):
    FreeType:       false

Tools used for command-line utilities:
    Cairo:          true
    Fontconfig:     true

Additional shapers (the more the better):
    Graphite2:      false

Platform shapers (not normally needed):
    CoreText:       false
    Uniscribe:      false

Other features:
    Documentation:      no
    GObject bindings:   false
    Introspection:      false
```

However, `make` fails with the following error:

```
In file included from hb-glib.cc:31:0:
hb-glib.h:50:22: error: 'GBytes' was not declared in this scope
 hb_glib_blob_create (GBytes *gbytes);
                      ^
hb-glib.h:50:30: error: 'gbytes' was not declared in this scope
 hb_glib_blob_create (GBytes *gbytes);
                              ^
hb-glib.cc:389:22: error: redefinition of 'hb_blob_t* hb_glib_blob_create'
 hb_glib_blob_create (GBytes *gbytes)
                      ^
In file included from hb-glib.cc:31:0:
hb-glib.h:50:1: error: 'hb_blob_t* hb_glib_blob_create' previously defined here
 hb_glib_blob_create (GBytes *gbytes);
 ^
hb-glib.cc:389:22: error: 'GBytes' was not declared in this scope
 hb_glib_blob_create (GBytes *gbytes)
                      ^
hb-glib.cc:389:30: error: 'gbytes' was not declared in this scope
 hb_glib_blob_create (GBytes *gbytes)
                              ^
make[4]: *** [libharfbuzz_la-hb-glib.lo] Error 1
```

I can't determine anything from the `config.log` file, but then again I'm not exactly sure what to look for. I'm guessing that perhaps there's an unmet dependency somewhere, but I'm kind of at a loss at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated and I'm happy to provide more info if needed. Thanks a lot.

If it's helpful, here is [the full config.log](https://s3.amazonaws.com/tnat1031-misc/config.log).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The glib [`GBytes` type](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Byte-Arrays.html#GBytes) was added in glib 2.32.

The version of glib is CentOS 5 is 2.12 which is **much** older.

The harfbuzz configure setup should be checking for a compatible version of glib and not getting as far as compiling before failing. That's a "bug" on their part.

You get to either use an older version of harfbuzz that can use the version of glib that CentOS 5 ships with or you get to build and "install" your own copy of glib too.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks very much for the answer. I will give this a shot and report back.

Comment: Update: I installed glib-2.4.1, then harfbuzz installed successfully, thanks.